# Add identical code to multiple combo boxes

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I have a worksheet with 960 combo boxes.  I need them to all have the same code attached:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
ActiveSheet.Range("a2").Select
End Sub
```

is there a way to attach this code to each combo box on the sheet automatically without the tedious task of doing it one by one?  In case it matters, the reason that I have attached this code is because when the combo box is selected, the hyperlinks and code on the sheet won't work until/unless the user clicks any cell.  If there is a Properties setting that takes care of this, then I would rather do that.

Comment: If all of the ComboBoxes are `Form Controls` then this is possible. If they are all `ActiveX` controls then this is not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455179/what-is-the-difference-between-form-controls-and-activex-control-in-excel-20 So, please update your post and let us know if you used `Form Controls` or `ActiveX` controls. The following post can help you determine if your ComboBoxes are `Form Controls` or `ActiveX` controls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38232366/how-to-find-and-select-checkbox-in-excel-using-vba/38234977#38234977

Comment: I did use activeX control because of the ability to adjust font size.  So I'm out of luck?

Comment: How is it done with a form control? Perhaps I will zoom the page and use form controls instead.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I'm looking for. I'll try it out in an hour or so. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on this Ralph!  SOF has been a tremendous help to my and I want this to continue.  Pardon my ignorance, but I don't know how to mark answers as correct.  I'm sorry.  How do I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116886/discussion-between-don-desrosiers-and-ralph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Create a ComboBox Collection

You'll need

- Custom class `ComboWrapper` to hold a reference to you combobox

  - Using WithEvents you'll capture the buttons Click event
- Module level collection variable to hold references to the `ComboWrapper` in memory

  - Use the `Worksheet_Activate()` to instantiate the collection

Insert a class

[image]

Rename it `ComboWrapper`

[image]

Insert this code into the `ComboWrapper` class

```
Public WithEvents combo As MSForms.ComboBox

Private Sub combo_Change()

    Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```

Insert this code into the `Worksheet Code Module`

```
Public ComboCollection As Collection

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim o As OLEObject
    Dim wrapper As ComboWrapper
    Set ComboCollection = New Collection

    For Each o In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        On Error Resume Next

        If o.progID = "Forms.ComboBox.1" Then
            Set wrapper = New ComboWrapper
            Set wrapper.combo = o.Object

            ComboCollection.Add wrapper
        End If

        On Error GoTo 0
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you read the requirements and comments? There are 960 *existing* ActiveX ComboBoxes. These are not form controls (MSForms). I don't think that the OP wants to re-create these 960 ComboBoxes just to suit your solution. Furthermore, with form controls your solution wouldn't even be necessary as all these ComboBoxes could share the same sub (no class modules necessary). On a side note: the OP has 960 ComboBoxes and not 960 CommandButtons.

Comment: @Ralph MSForms controls **are** ActiveX. This is a *much* better solution than using code to create hundreds of identical procedures.

Comment: @Rory If Form Controls are ActiveX controls then I don't quite understand this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455179/what-is-the-difference-between-form-controls-and-activex-control-in-excel-20 Furthermore, I specifically posted my solution because Form Controls (on sheets) can share one sub in a module whereas each ActiveX control (on sheets) has their own sub: `Private Sub NameOfActiveXcontrol_Click()`. My solution works with **one** sub for all 960 controls. But surely, I missing something or maybe I don't quite understand what you and Thomas mean. So, please help me understand.

Comment: @Ralph Form controls are not the same as MSForms controls! :) (good old Microsoft) Form controls are part of the Excel application; MSForms controls come from the fm20.dll and are the ones you use on userforms. Thomas' solution puts the actual processing code into a class and then creates an instance of that class for each control on the worksheet. Also, although your solution is one sub, it creates 960 subs, so any maintenance is going to be horrendous.

Comment: @Ralph  I created a sample file to demonstrate how to use a custom class  and a collection to group controls: [Download WrapControls.xlsm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gviph3pb8ttijih/WrapControls.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: @Rory Thanks.  I meant to respond to Ralph's but was busy and forgot about it.  I linked him a sample file that will hopefully clear thing up a little.

Comment: This works as it is, how would we change the actual combobox that was clicked< like a different interior color for example.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `ActiveX` controls the name of the sub is preassigned. For example: if you click on the `ComboBox1` then the name for the sub **must** be `Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()` and the sub **must** be on the sheet where the ComboBox is located. So, if you have 960 ComboBoxes then you need to have 960 subs on the sheet where these ComboBoxes are located.

But here is the good news. You can use VBA to write the VBA code for you. The following `sub` will go through all sheets and all ActiveX ComboBoxes and write the code for you. Afterwards, the code is dropped into the `Immediate` window of the VBE.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GenerateComboBoxCode()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim obj As OLEObject
Dim strVBA As String

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each obj In ws.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(obj.Object) = "ComboBox" Then
            strVBA = strVBA & "Private Sub " & obj.Name & "_DropButtonClick() " & Chr(10)
            strVBA = strVBA & "ActiveSheet.Range(""a2"").Select " & Chr(10)
            strVBA = strVBA & "End Sub " & Chr(10)
        End If
    Next obj
    Debug.Print "------------------------------------------------------"
    Debug.Print "--- Code for sheet " & ws.Name & ":"
    Debug.Print "------------------------------------------------------"
    Debug.Print strVBA
Next ws

End Sub
```

But in your case (960 ComboBoxes) the `Immediate` window might not be enough and you might have to store / save the VBA code on a sheet instead.

### Update:

Since the `Immediate` window cannot fit the entire code, here is a little update to the above solution:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GenerateComboBoxCode()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim obj As OLEObject
Dim strVBA As String
Dim appWord As Object
Dim docWord As Object

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    strVBA = strVBA & "------------------------------------------------------" & Chr(10)
    strVBA = strVBA & "--- Code for sheet " & ws.Name & ":" & Chr(10)
    strVBA = strVBA & "------------------------------------------------------" & Chr(10)
    For Each obj In ws.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(obj.Object) = "ComboBox" Then
            strVBA = strVBA & "Private Sub " & obj.Name & "_DropButtonClick() " & Chr(10)
            strVBA = strVBA & "ActiveSheet.Range(""a2"").Select " & Chr(10)
            strVBA = strVBA & "End Sub " & Chr(10)
        End If
    Next obj
Next ws

Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set docWord = appWord.Documents.Add
docWord.Paragraphs.Add
docWord.Paragraphs(docWord.Paragraphs.Count).Range.Text = strVBA
appWord.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Now, a new `Word Document` is created and the entire code is copied into that word document. Afterwards, you can copy all of the document's content and paste it over into the sheet where the ComboBoxes reside.

Comment: this worked perfectly and is exactly what I'm looking for.  However, 2 important issues remain.  why did it only write code for 36 boxes?  and why did it make 2 of every SUB?  I have deleted all of the ambiguous SUBs but now I need it to complete the job.  I know that you referenced this issue when you commented about 960 boxes, but I don't understand the workaround.

Comment: Ralph... spectacular!  Thank you!