# Assign a value to a cell by using 4 multiple choice checkboxes

Tags: vba, excel

I would like please to assign a value to a cell by using 4 multiple choice check boxes which their value is 1 per each box if their condition is true. I would like to sum up their value in the linked cell so that cell value can vary. If for instance:

1. all checkboxes condition is true the value in the linked cell is 4
2. A few of them are true the value in the linked cell can vary from 1-3
3. All of them are false the value in the linked cell is 0

   ```
        If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Range("D2").Value = 1


        If CheckBox1.Value = False Then Range("D2").Value = 0 etc.
   ```

I wish to solve this problem by using a vba macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer to my problem:

Option Explicit

```
   Sub CheckBox1_Click()


Dim count As Integer
If (count = Null) Then
count = 0
End If

count = 0
If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1").ControlFormat = xlOn Then count = count + 1
If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 2").ControlFormat = xlOn Then count = count + 1
If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 3").ControlFormat = xlOn Then count = count + 1
If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 4").ControlFormat = xlOn Then count = count + 1
Range("A1").Value = count
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Just set the macro foreach checkbox before clicking it.

```
Public count As Integer

Public Sub btn_Click()
Dim cbName As String

If (count = Null) Then
    count = 0
End If

cbName = Application.Caller

If (Sheets("Tabelle1").Shapes(cbName).ControlFormat.Value = xlOn And count < 4) Then
    count = count + 1
ElseIf (count > 0) Then
    count = count - 1
End If
    Range("A1").Value = count
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have problem Tizzu with type mismatch

Comment: you using ActiveX checkboxes i guess which makes it alot harder 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282148/add-identical-code-to-multiple-combo-boxes
If you dont care about format use FormControll Checkboxes

Comment: What would you suggest instead?

Comment: I checked again and I am using form control Checkboxes and it keeps giving type mismatch error. Any clue?

Comment: either using form control checkboxes or going though Inzina's tutorial (SO post linked above)

Comment: yes I have changed it in Sheet1. Temporarily is the name of my sheet

Comment: I mean this little guide located under “Form Controls” on the Developer Tab > Insert menu: checkbox. Is it not correct?

Comment: Public count As Integer

Public Sub btn_Click()
Dim CheckBox1 As String

If (count = Null) Then
    count = 0
End If

cbName = Application.Caller

If (Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes(CheckBox1).ControlFormat.Value = xlOn And count < 4) Then
    count = count + 1
ElseIf (count > 0) Then
    count = count - 1
End If
    Range("A1").Value = count
End Sub

Comment: You renamed my string variable for the checkbox's name http://imgur.com/a/xRRJb (line 7 my upload isnt working ...)
but you didnt rename it where the variable gets initialized so CheckBox1 is a empty String

Comment: Public count As Integer
Public Sub btn_Click()
Dim CheckBox1 As String
If (count = Null) Then
count = 0
End If
    CheckBox1 = Application.Caller
If (Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes(CheckBox1).ControlFormat.Value = xlOn And count < 4) Then
    count = count + 1
ElseIf (count > 0) Then
    count = count - 1
End If
    Range("A1").Value = count
End Sub

Comment: CheckBox1 = Application.Caller Type mismatch 13

Comment: Just tried it in excel 2016 and 2010 works fine in both for me
Im sorry cant help there then

Comment: No worries, you have done your best. Thanks a lot for your help. I will mark the answer anyway. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way. based on linked cells get the 1 if true or Zero if false. and then sum all values.

[image]

[image]

for VBA solution

```
    Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Dim str As Integer
    str = 0
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then str = str + 1
    If CheckBox2.Value = True Then str = str + 1
    If CheckBox3.Value = True Then str = str + 1
    If CheckBox4.Value = True Then str = str + 1
    Range("D2").Value = str
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I would prefer to sort it by using a vba macro. As you can imagine this question doesn't include the big picture.

Comment: Hi Maddy thanks but I have inserted your code and while I am clicking the checkboxes there is no change to cell D2 as I would like. Do you have any insight regarding that?

Comment: Also when I run the code a window pops up saying object required. Any clue?

Comment: are you using **ActiveX Controls** check boxs?

Comment: Yes I using them